# Hadoop Mapreduce read input from remote machine

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Scenario: I want to run a map reduce program on my **local Hadoop cluster** processing **1.5T** data from remote machine. But my local Hadoop cluster only have **100G** hard disk space.

Input data: 1.5T data from remote machine.
Local machine disk size: 100G.

Question: How can I read 1.5T data directly from remote machine?

I know there exist 2 way of doing this.

1. Specify a AWS S3 path directly as input path for mapreduce program. Unfortunately, I can't upload my data to S3 because it is not allowed.
2. Use HDFS [HFTP](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hftp.html). However, I can't install HDFS on remote machine because I have no permission.

Is there any other way to read files from remote machine in mapreduce program?

Comment: Hadoop helps by colocating the data with the processing. If that's not possible in your case, the performance will be a big hit. Am not even sure what you can achieve by doing parallel processing in that case. However you can mount that disk as a local disk on all nodes and use it as a local disk.

Comment: Thanks Preeti, I agree with you. If the remote data machine are not HDFS, it doesn't make sense to run MapReduce on local machine because they are not going to run in parallel. In this case, I would rather running a simple java/python program on remote machine instead of unsuitable MapReduce.